# Any AS3 alternatives to Colin Moock's approach to visible width/height of DisplayObject?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, displayobject

Has anyone got any alternatives to what Colin Moock has coded to [GET VISIBLE WIDTH/HEIGHT OF A DISPLAY OBJECT](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000292.html) in ActionScript 3? That esp. in perspective of DisplayObjects that have 3D transforms applied and visible dimensions of which you need to consider for a calculation.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Moock's solution should take 3D transformations into account since it's just creating a BitmapData object of the display object, then getting the size based on that. Are there limitations in Moock's solution that you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Moock's solution is currently the only possible way to do it, but what we'd actually need is a built-in property to DisplayObjectContainer that would do this measuring in a more optimised way, e.g. visibleBounds or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the appropriate functionality is entirely missing from ActionScript 3 at this point, please [vote for the feature request at Adobe](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-741)!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this... try: displayObject.transform.pixelBounds().

Comment: __pixelBounds__ is not a method but a property of Transform class, thus the above code would result in error. 

What pixelBounds will retrieve is the Rectangle object with the bounds of the DisplayObject before transformations, unfortunately.

Comment: There's a workaround that deploys BitmapData at http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/as/actionscript-3-lacks-functionality-for-visible-bounds-of-displayobject